Indent problem with Clicker in Matplotlib
I have taught myself enough Python/PyQt6/Qt Designer in Visual Studio Code to create a program that inverts a positive RGB image into a true negative. The program plots the positive inputs against the corrected negative outputs. The user can click on the graph to lighten or darken selected tonal areas and generate a new plot.
The main snippet below shows loading a preset file containing the list of x inputs and y outputs to be plotted. Because the event_handler used to record the clicks does not show the point clicked on, I imported Clicker to do this. It works fine in the stand alone snippet shown below the main snippet, but when inserted into the main program it does not work.
In the stand alone snippet "klicker" is shown as a "(variable) klicker: clicker". In the main program "klicker" is shown " "klicker" is not accessed". If the 'klicker" line is indented back one level, "klicker" become"live" and is shown as      "(variable) klicker: clicker" but "ax1" is now not accessed.
I have been able to research and solve many other problems but cannot find any information on this.
Thanks
class Guide_2(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        Preset, ok=QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()   
        fName = Preset
        with open(Preset,"rb") as loaded_file:
            Xgrid,Ygrid,ax,ay,Dnsty=pickle.load(loaded_file)

        Y0=Ygrid[0];Y1=Ygrid[1];Y2=Ygrid[2];Y3=Ygrid[3];Y4=Ygrid[4];Y5=Ygrid[5];Y6=Ygrid[6];Y7=Ygrid[7]
        Y8=Ygrid[8];Y9=Ygrid[9];Y10=Ygrid[10];Y11=Ygrid[11];Y12=Ygrid[12];Y13=Ygrid[13];Y14=Ygrid[14]
        Y15=Ygrid[15];Y16=Ygrid[16];Y17=Ygrid[17]
        Ygrid=[Y0,Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4,Y5,Y6,Y7,Y8,Y9,Y10,Y11,Y12,Y13,Y14,Y15,Y16,Y17]   

        P0=Xgrid[0];P1=Xgrid[1];P2=Xgrid[2];P3=Xgrid[3];P4=Xgrid[4];P5=Xgrid[5];P6=Xgrid[6];P7=Xgrid[7]
        P8=Xgrid[8];P9=Xgrid[9];P10=Xgrid[10];P11=Xgrid[11];P12=Xgrid[12];P13=Xgrid[13];P14=Xgrid[14]
        P15=Xgrid[15];P16=Xgrid[16];P17=Xgrid[17]
        Xgrid=[P0,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,P10,P11,P12,P13,P14,P15,P16,P17] 
        
        fig = Figure(figsize=(6, 6), dpi=100)
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax1.set_ylabel('Log Neg RGB')
        ax1.set_xlabel('Log Positive RGB')
        ax1.set_title('Plot1')
        ax1.set_xlim(3.3,4.95)
        ax1.set_ylim(4.95,3.3)
        ax1.plot(Xgrid,Ygrid)
        klicker=clicker(ax1,['event'], markers=['x'])
        plt.show()

#Stand alone snippet

    fig = plt.figure()  
    fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax1.set_ylabel('Neg RGB')
    ax1.set_title('Plot1')

    ax=[1,2,3,4,5]
    ay=[1,2,3,4,5]
    klicker=clicker(ax1,['event'], markers=['x'])
    ax1.plot(ax,ay)
    plt.show()


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'm struggling to understand your code; but the main question is are you actually instantiating Guide_2() anywhere?  Since you've placed your code all in the constructor of Guide_2(), you'd have to instantiate it to run your code.  Or did I misunderstand something?

Guide_2() runs inside a QtDesigner application that, among other things, creates the Xgrid and Ygrid lists.
